# Vscode keeps opening ~foundation/binding.dart when trying to debug

Tags: flutter

Yesterday it was fine, Today It shows the following line of the mentioned file :

[image]

It doesn't show anything in the debug console and the file is not mine.
What is this and how can I make it show me the exact line of my codes which cause the error.
Thanks In advance

Edit: to make it searchable by users:

```
ui.SingletonFlutterWindow get window => ui.window;
```

File path :
~flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\foundation\binding.dart

Comment: looks like a new bug bothering me for more than 3 days